# How to dynamically determine the actual type of a literal of Object type

Tags: java, casting

I have a `HashMap` with some values. I want to iterate over each value in the map and call a method `myFun()` for every value.

`myFun()` is an overloaded method takes two arguments: One is String and other can be of type Integer, Decimal, Float, String, String[], Value, Value[] etc:

```
    Map<String, Object> NodesFound = new HashMap<>();
    String[] children = {"child1","child2","child3","child4"};
    NodesFound.put("String", "Hi its a string");
    NodesFound.put("Number", 1);
    NodesFound.put("children", children);
    Set<String> nodeLabels = NodesFound.keySet();
    for (String label : nodeLabels) {
        Object value = NodesFound.get(label);
        Class<?> theClass = value.getClass();
        myFun("myVal", theClass.cast(value))
    }
```

Expected: `myFun()` should not give Type mismatch error.

Actual:
The following compilation error is coming:
The method myFun(String, Value) in the type Node is not applicable for the arguments (String, 
     capture#3-of ?)

Comment: Obviously you can do what you like in your own code, but when asking for help, it's **much** better to stick to normal naming conventions so your question is clear and the naming isn't tripping people up. `NodesFound` in the above should be `nodesFound`.

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers at some point! Unfortunately new users often forget about doing that...

Answer (score 1):

To use `cast`, you would need the `theClass` variable to be declared with a non-wildcard type parameter (e.g., `Class<String>`), which you can't do if it's going to refer to classes of varying underlying types.

It's ugly, but I don't think you can avoid `instanceof` here, which probably means it's worth revisiting why you have various different types in the same map.

But if you're going to do that, then:

```
if (value instanceof Integer) {
    myFun("myVal", (Integer)value);
} else if (value instanceof String) {
    myFun("myVal", (String)value);
} else if (value instanceof ...) {
    // ...
} else {
    throw new AppropriateException();
}
```

Again, though, chains like that suggest you want to rethink `NodesFound`.

Comment: You beat me by a second, and you even have code! But: why casting to int, not Integer? And merry Xmas Mr. Crowder!

Comment: @GhostCat - Thanks, Merry Christmas! For some reason, I thought the OP was using `int`. Reading the question, I can't see why... :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can't work.

The compiler decides at compile time which overloaded method to pick.

You can't "postpone" this to runtime.

The only ways to make this work:

- use *instanceof* and static casts for all the different cases
- try to design a solution that works using overwriting, as that happens at runtime (but that might require a completely different design)